# trying to make gradient using boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I need to know how can I specify some variable parameters to my background color?? 
I'm trying to use JavaScript and i want to make this shape :

[image]

I know the parameters, 
My approach was to take the initial division, append a child division to it with smaller size and different background color..
However, for this to work i needed to use this : `box[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255-10*i, 255-10*i, 255-10*i)"`

Which didnt work, And i was told that the rgb only takes integers parameters, so i tried to do this:

```
color = 255-10*i;
box[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(color,color,color)";
```

which led to the same error.. Any idea how to proceed? 
Note: 1- I'm using that code in a for loop to create say 20 nested division with different color and size
2- I'm obliged to do it using javascript with no manipulation with neither html nor css files...
3- I need it as fast as possible( Studying for the exam ) 
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to concatenate the string with the value of color. right now you're just making a string with the word color inside it:

```
color = 255-10*i;
box[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + "," + color + "," + color + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the variables as strings

```
box[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(color,color,color)";
```

Should be

```
box[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
```